# MAtlab - is it possible to replace this for-loop with one convn?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code where data is a matrix of [128 64 10] and W is a matrix of [8 64 50]. I'm computing the convolution of m

```
for j = 1 : size(obj.W, 3) 
  output(:, :, :, j) = convn(data, obj.W(:, :, j), 'valid');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
output = convn(data, reshape(obj.W, [8 64 1 50]), 'full');
output = output(8:end-7,64,:,:);
```

That doesn't mean it will be faster, though, as you compute many times more values.